# Parsing an HREF from an HTML string using a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse a link to a zip file out of html.  The name of this zipfile changes every month.  Here is a snippet of the HTML I need to parse:

```html
<a href="http://nppes.viva-it.com/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_Mar_2012.zip">
```

The string I need to get is "http://nppes.viva-it.com/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_Mar_2012.zip" so I can download the file using WebClient.  The only portion of that zip file URL that remains constant from month to month is "http://nppes.viva-it.com/".  Is there a way using a regular expression to parse the full URL, "http://nppes.viva-it.com/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_Mar_2012.zip", out of the HTML?

Comment: In the general case, using a regular expression to parse HTML *won't* work.  However narrow you build the pattern, a perfectly legal HTML file can defeat it.  Use a real parser

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there will only ever be one ZIP linked to on the page, no problem:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"http://nppes\.viva-it\.com/.+\.zip");

re.Match(html).Value // To get the matched URL
```

[Here's a demo.](http://ideone.com/P3jeS)

Answer (score 1):

By using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
var html = "<a href=\"http://nppes.viva-it.com/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_Mar_2012.zip\">";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var anchor = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a");
var href = anchor.GetAttributeValue("href", null);
```

now `href` variable holds `"http://nppes.viva-it.com/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_Mar_2012.zip"` value.

Isn't it simplier than regex?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a raw regex - uses branch reset.
The answer is in capture buffer 2.

```
<a 
  (?=\s) 
  (?= (?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*? (?<=\s)
    href \s*=
    (?|
        (?> \s* (['"]) \s* (http://nppes\.viva-it\.com/ (?:(?!\g{-2}) .)+ \.zip ) \s*     \g{-2} )
      | (?> (?!\s*['"]) \s* () (http://nppes\.viva-it\.com/ [^\s>]* \.zip ) (?=\s|>) )
    )
  )
  \s+ (?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+ 
>
```

Not sure if C# can do branch reset. If it can't, this variation works.
The answer is always the result of capture buffer 2 catted  with capture buffer 3.

```
<a 
  (?=\s) 
  (?= (?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*? (?<=\s)
    href \s*=
    (?:
        (?> \s* (['"]) \s* (http://nppes\.viva-it\.com/ (?:(?!\g{-2}) .)+ \.zip ) \s* \g{-2} )
      | (?> (?!\s*['"]) \s* (http://nppes\.viva-it\.com/ [^\s>]* \.zip ) (?=\s|>) )
    )
  )
  \s+ (?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+ 
>
```